# Worst Case Performance of Quicksort

Tags: algorithm, quicksort, asymptotic-complexity

I am trying to prove the following worst-case scenario for the Quicksort algorithm but am having some trouble.  Initially, we have an array of size n, where n = ij.  The idea is that at every partition step of Quicksort, you end up with two sub-arrays where one is of size i and the other is of size i(j-1).  i in this case is an integer constant greater than 0.  I have drawn out the recursive tree of some examples and understand why this is a worst-case scenario and that the running time will be theta(n^2).  To prove this, I've used the iteration method to solve the recurrence equation:

```
T(n) = T(ij) = m if j = 1
T(n) = T(ij) = T(i) + T(i(j-1)) + cn if j > 1

T(i) = m
T(2i) = m + m + c*2i = 2m + 2ci
T(3i) = m + 2m + 2ci + 3ci = 3m + 5ci
```

So it looks like the recurrence is:

```
                  j 
T(n) = jm + ci * sum k - 1 
                 k=1
```

At this point, I'm a bit lost as to what to do.  It looks the summation at the end will result in j^2 if expanded out, but I need to show that it somehow equals n^2.  Any explanation on how to continue with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Pay attention, the quicksort algorithm worst case scenario is when you have two subproblems of size 0 and n-1. In this scenario, you have this recurrence equations for each level:

```
T(n)   = T(n-1) + T(0) < -- at first level of tree
T(n-1) = T(n-2) + T(0) < -- at second level of tree
T(n-2) = T(n-3) + T(0) < -- at third level of tree
.
.
.
```

The sum of costs at each level is an arithmetic serie:

```
        n       n(n-1)
T(n) = sum k =  ------ ~ n^2 (for n -> +inf)
       k=1        2
```

It is O(n^2).

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I understand that that is also a worst-case scenario and that is the one that is commonly shown as examples in textbooks and online.  I actually need help with the scenario I posted, which is also another worst-case but I am unable to find examples.

Comment: Based on the algorithms literature, this is the only worst-case scenario for quick sort algorithm. There aren't other worst case scenarios. If you have, for example, two subproblems of size 1 and n-2 (most similar to the worst-case) the situation is better than the worst-case scenario. The scenario you described looks like strange because, the problem size, during the computation will increase. The algorithm will never stop. It doesn't follow the divide and conquer approach. The quicksort algorithm follow the divide and conquer approach.

Answer (score 0):

Its a problem of simple mathematics. The complexity as you have calculated correctly is

O(jm + ij^2)

what you have found out is a parameterized complextiy. The standard O(n^2) is contained in this as follows - assuming i=1 you have a standard base case so m=O(1) hence j=n therefore we get O(n^2). if you put ij=n you will get O(nm/i+n^2/i) . Now what you should remember is that m is a function of i depending upon what you will use as the base case algorithm hence m=f(i) thus you are left with O(nf(i)/i + n^2/i). Now again note that since there is no linear algorithm for general sorting hence f(i) = omega(ilogi) which will give you O(nlogi + n^2/i).  So you have only one degree of freedom that is i. Check that for any value of i you cannot reduce it below nlogn which is the best bound for comparison based.

Now what I am confused is that you are doing some worst case analysis of quick sort. This is not the way its done. When you say worst case it implies you are using randomization in which case the worst case will always be when i=1 hence the worst case bound will be O(n^2). An elegant way to do this is explained in randomized algorithm book by R. Motwani and Raghavan alternatively if you are a programmer then you look at Cormen.